# javascript data attribute read by name when name is dynamically generated

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a property to a Javascript Object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)
>   [Dynamic property names for loop of object Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566465/dynamic-property-names-for-loop-of-object-javascript)

In success of javascript function I receveing data and it look like this:

```
data.lvl1
data.lvl2
data.lvl3
...
```

let say I have only 3 elements in data and I would like to loop for each of them and rise alert for every level:

```
for(a = 1; a<= 3; a++)
{
   alert(data.lvl + a);
   //I would like to read lvl1, lvl2, lvl3
}
```

This approach is obviously wrong. 
Please explain how to reach lvl1, lvl2 in loop when lvl number is based on increasing `a`.

Comment: If you only have those properties, you better use a `for...in` loop though (if the order does not matter): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in. See als [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/85992/218196).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access a property name using a string, then use square bracket notation.

```
foo.bar === foo['bar']
```

Such:

```
alert(data['lvl' + a]);
```

But it would be better to restructure your data so that you had something like:

```
data = { lvl: [1,2,3] }
```

instead of

```
data = { lvl1: 1, lvl2: 2, lvl3: 3 }
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir, feeling a little ashamed :)

Comment: so should Quentin, for not bothering to find one of the dozens of other identical questions ;-)

Comment: yeah, it must be redundant question but I didn't know how to express my question in short way so I didn't find any helpfull answers. Sorry for that