# Interpret a javascript concatenated string as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I get data via ajax. 
In results `data.items` I have:

```
image1, image2, ..., imageN
```

each represents an image name like `109298109991.jpg`

I try to write a function

```
$.each(images, function(i,item){

  var image_n = 'data.items.image' + (i+1); 

  console.log(image_n.value);

  images_restruct.push({ 
  href: '/images/flowercatalog/'+ image_n
  title: 'Image' + i
 });
});
```

But `image_n` is interpreted as string `data.items.image1`, `data.items.image2` ... `data.items.imageN`, not as `01010101001.jpg` ... `00001112121.jpg`

Comment: Well, `image_n` *is* a string.

Comment: 'data.items.image' : This makes it a string and not the actual image.Remove the quotes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic property names for loop of object Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566465/dynamic-property-names-for-loop-of-object-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, 
var image_n = data.items['image' + (i+1)];
Work as expected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)

Answer (score 3):

```
$.each(data.items, function(i, item){
    images_restruct.push({ 
        href: '/images/flowercatalog/'+ data.items[item],
        title: 'Image' + i
    });
});
```